# Repeat button press behaving differently

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm writing a Watch app in Swift. I have a grid of boxes that I don't have enough reputation to post an image of. There is a group which underlies each row. The group has a background color. Each box is a button. The first box in the row has no image or color and just displays the group's background color and when pressed it resets the other boxes on the row with the same background image and color as they originally started with. The other 3 buttons on a row have their own background image and background color.

When one of the buttons is pressed it removes the button image which displays the button background, which is just a solid color and is different than the row color. You can see this at [the correct response to button press](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/255492/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-25%20at%208.26.49%20AM.png). Pressing the button a second time returns the image as I want it to. This looks the same as the first screenshot. However, subsequent cycles through a button no longer display the background color of the button, instead it displays the group's (row's) background color. You can see this at [not behaving properly](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/255492/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-25%20at%208.22.13%20AM.png). So the first press works and removes the background image, displaying the button's background color. Even presses return the button to it's original background image. Subsequent odd presses display the row background color. This action is the same whether one presses the button a 2nd time or uses the row button (first button in the row) to reset the row.

How do I fix subsequent odd presses to act as the first press does and display the button's background color?

My controller code for a row and a button (blueRed) is below.

```
@IBOutlet var clearBlueButton: WKInterfaceButton!
@IBAction func clearBlue() {
    if (blueRedDead) {
        blueRed.setBackgroundImageNamed( "livered.png");
        blueRed.setBackgroundColor( UIColor (red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0));
        blueRedDead = false;
    }
    if (blueBlackDead) {
        blueBlack.setBackgroundImageNamed( "liveblack.png");
        blueBlack.setBackgroundColor( UIColor (red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0));
        blueBlackDead = false;
    }
    if (blueYellowDead) {
        blueYellow.setBackgroundImageNamed( "liveyellow.png");
        blueYellow.setBackgroundColor( UIColor (red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0));
        blueYellowDead = false;
    }
}
@IBOutlet var blueRed:
    WKInterfaceButton!
@IBAction func blueStrikeRed() {
    if (!blueRedDead) {
        blueRedDead=true;
        blueRed.setBackgroundImage( nil);
        blueRed.setBackgroundColor( UIColor (red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0));
    }
    else {
        blueRedDead=false;
        blueRed.setBackgroundImageNamed( "livered.png");
        blueRed.setBackgroundColor( UIColor (red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0));
    }
}
```

Thanks.
Craig

Comment: Any way you could leave a link to the screenshot? Having a hard time following the description but im intrigued by your issue.

Comment: I've added links to screenshots as @ChrisSlowik suggested. Since I can only add 2 links above, here's [the initial view of the grid](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/255492/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-25%20at%208.26.43%20AM.png).

Comment: Ah i see.. i think its more correct if you say "subsequent presses display NO background color - clear". Anyway, reading through this again. images helped.